# Gradient above of gray scale image css

Tags: jquery, css, overlay, grayscale

I have the following code , an image of a background of gray scale and the div containing the image , it has a gradient .

The problem I have is that the gradient also appears in grayscale .

I need the gradient is above the gray scale image .

Any ideas ?

```
<div id="contentVisi" class="overlaySeg"></div>

#contentVisi {
    background-image: url("images/visitantes.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 586px;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.overlaySeg::before {
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(74% 27%, circle cover, rgba(227,79,120,0) 0%, rgba(227,79,120,0.29) 29%, rgba(227,79,120,0.61) 61%, rgba(227,79,120,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(74% 27%, circle cover, rgba(227,79,120,0) 0%, rgba(227,79,120,0.29) 29%, rgba(227,79,120,0.61) 61%, rgba(227,79,120,1) 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(74% 27%, circle cover, rgba(227,79,120,0) 0%, rgba(227,79,120,0.29) 29%, rgba(227,79,120,0.61) 61%, rgba(227,79,120,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(74% 27%, circle cover, rgba(227,79,120,0) 0%, rgba(227,79,120,0.29) 29%, rgba(227,79,120,0.61) 61%, rgba(227,79,120,1) 100%);
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 74% 27%, rgba(227,79,120,0) 0%, rgba(227,79,120,0.29) 29%, rgba(227,79,120,0.61) 61%, rgba(227,79,120,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e34f78', endColorstr='#e34f78', GradientType=1 );
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 586px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.6;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your div inside another div and add the colorful gradient to that div's.

HTML:

```
<div class="overlaySeg"><div id="contentVisi"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#contentVisi {
    background-image: url("http://s3.amazonaws.com/colorcombos-images/users/1/color-schemes/color-scheme-375-main.png?v=20120505082910");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 487px;
    height: 290px;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.overlaySeg {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.overlaySeg:after {
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(74% 27%, circle cover, rgba(227,79,120,0) 0%, rgba(227,79,120,0.29) 29%, rgba(227,79,120,0.61) 61%, rgba(227,79,120,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(74% 27%, circle cover, rgba(227,79,120,0) 0%, rgba(227,79,120,0.29) 29%, rgba(227,79,120,0.61) 61%, rgba(227,79,120,1) 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(74% 27%, circle cover, rgba(227,79,120,0) 0%, rgba(227,79,120,0.29) 29%, rgba(227,79,120,0.61) 61%, rgba(227,79,120,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(74% 27%, circle cover, rgba(227,79,120,0) 0%, rgba(227,79,120,0.29) 29%, rgba(227,79,120,0.61) 61%, rgba(227,79,120,1) 100%);
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 74% 27%, rgba(227,79,120,0) 0%, rgba(227,79,120,0.29) 29%, rgba(227,79,120,0.61) 61%, rgba(227,79,120,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e34f78', endColorstr='#e34f78', GradientType=1 );
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.6;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Codepen Demo: http://codepen.io/saqibamin/pen/jWGJEB